# Как найти нужные элементы при парсинге на AngleSharp

Tags: c#, dom, anglesharp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно найти .simple_price .price-num но только **НЕ** те где индекс .simple_price-row равен 0;

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
        var items = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.simple_price__bodys__item .simple_price-row")
                            .Where(item => item.Index() != 0)
                            .Children(".simple_price-col")
                            .Children(".price-num");
```

Я написал такой код но в нем мне смущает то что при изменении может быть много методов .Children

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я питаюсь парсить страницу. Мне нужно получить все классы которые содержат "price-num" но только не те где его родитель с классом .simple_price-row первый по индексу

Comment: `document.QuerySelectorAll(".simple_price-row:first-child .price-num");`

Comment: Как всегда, пришел @aepot и всех спас!

Comment: @aepot Мне нужно чтобы это были все элементы только не первый а так находит именно первый

Comment: @VM тогда вы забыли `НЕ` во фразе `...только те где индекс .simple_price-row равен 0`

Comment: @iKuzmichov  "но только __НЕ__ те где его родитель с классом .simple_price-row первый по индексу"

Comment: `document.QuerySelectorAll(".simple_price-row:not(:first-child) .price-num");`

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, решено

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой запрос

```
var items = document.QuerySelectorAll(".simple_price-row:not(:first-child) .price-num");
```